# How to remove all filters from a file using code in another file?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to remove all filters from file `TestA.xlsx`.

Sometimes filters are enabled in `TestA.xlsx`. If you open `TestB` afterwards not all the data gets copied to file `TestB`.

So how this works is that if "file A" is open and you open "file B", "file B" checks if "file A" is active.  If it is active it will copy everything from "file A" in worksheet TestA to "file B" inside worksheet `TestB`.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim WB As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WB = Workbooks("Test.xlsx")
    If Err Then
        MsgBox "Test" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "" & "Test" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Test" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Test"
        'ThisWorkbook.Close
    End If

    Workbooks("TestA.xlsx").Worksheets("TestA").ShowAllData
    Workbooks("TestA.xlsx").Worksheets("TestA").Range("A2:AF666").Copy _
    Workbooks("TestB.xlsm").Worksheets("TestB").Range("A2")
    Worksheets("TestC").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="JA"
    Workbooks("TestB.xlsm").Worksheets("TestB").Range("B2:AF666").Copy _
    Workbooks("TestB.xlsm").Worksheets("TestC").Range("B2")

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: You can do `Workbooks("TestA.xlsx").Worksheets("TestA").AutoFilterMode = False` to remove any filter first, and only then do the copy operations.

Comment: This remove the hole filter is there an option to just disable the options without removing the hole filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Remove Filters

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Const swbName As String = "TestA.xlsx"
    Const sName As String = "TestA"
    Const dName As String = "TestB"
    Const d2Name As String = "TestC"
    
    If Not isWorkbookOpen(sName) Then
        MsgBox "The workbook '" & sName & "' is not open."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Workbooks(swbName).Worksheets(sName)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dws2 As Worksheet: Set dws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(d2Name)
    
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    sws.Range("A2:AF666").Copy dws.Range("A2")
    
    dws2.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="JA"
    ' This makes no sense, you cannot copy to a non-contiguous range.
    'dws.Range("B2:AF666").Copy dw2.Range("B2")
 
End Sub

Function isWorkbookOpen( _
    ByVal FileName As String) _
As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set ws = Workbooks(FileName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    isWorkbookOpen = Not wb Is Nothing
End Function
```